# Update version attribute of a powershell file

Tags: powershell, version, versioning

Is it possible to add version information to a powershell (ps1) file.

[image]

Comment: No, because the metadata of which you seek is a [VersionInfo resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx) that can only be added to an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know.

If it would be possible it would probably be by using a keyword in the [comment based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx), but I haven't seen one there.